# EKS 1.21.5 - fails on "topologySpreadConstraints"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Trying to test Pod Topology for the for the time. I chose to deploy it with a standard nginx deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
      whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
      labelSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
      labelSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

But deploying fails with the following error:

```
➜  Dev kubectl apply -f nginx-test-deployment.yml                                                   
error: error validating "nginx-test-deployment.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "topologySpreadConstraints" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I am using EKS v1.21.5 and `topologySpreadConstraints` is available from v1.18.

```
➜  ~ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:10:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.5-eks-bc4871b", GitCommit:"5236faf39f1b7a7dabea8df12726f25608131aa9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-29T23:32:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Can you check your kubectl client version? or can you put the output of `kubectl version` command? Because as you said, there is no deprecation/deletion declared for `topologySpreadConstraints` in official documents : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Added it to the question details. My client version is v1.21.5.
Did I not put `topologySpreadConstraints` under the right `spec`? I doubt it..

Comment: It should be part of the pod spec `spec.template.spec` instead of the top level deployment spec.

Comment: Very happy to see you found the problem & solved it :)

Comment: it would be nice to write own answer

Answer (score 1):

It has to be defined in the POD's spec, read more about this field by running `kubectl explain Pod.spec.topologySpreadConstraints`.

Hence, move this configuration from `Deployment.spec.` to `Deployment.spec.template.spec.`.

For instance:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: nginx
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: nginx
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```